# How to pass data from Form to Class method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't figure out how to pass data from a form's TextBox to a class method for calculation and then get the result back to the form to display in a TextBox or ListBox or whatever. I keep getting

> Cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `System.Windows.Forms.Textbox`

exception in my class.

For my setup I have a form with three textboxes (TxtFirstNumber, TxtSecondNumber, TxtResult) and a button (BtnCalculate). When I click the button I want the two numbers to get passed to the class to add and the result to appear on the form textbox TxtResult. I have a form called "form1" and a class called "class1".

This is my code so far:

```
class class1
{
    public static void AddTwoNumbers(int FirstNumber, int SecondNumber, ref TextBox TxtResult)
    {
        TxtResult = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
}

public partial class form1 : Form
{
    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1.AddTwoNumbers(Convert.ToInt32(TxtFirstNumber.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TxtSecondNumber.Text), ref TxtResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are just learning c#, I will tell you that any use of the `ref` keyword is strongly discouraged. There are not many common use cases for it and you certainly do not need it in that method

Comment: and for sure its not needed here (ref). And in general dont make the calculation function do the UI. (Separation of logic and presentation). Add2numbers should return the value and then the caller should display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use text property of the textbox. Answer is in the error message `"Cannot inplicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox'"`

```
TxtResult.Text = (FirstNumber + SecondNumber).ToString();
```

Comment: and maybe a ToString() - cant assign a number to a string value

Comment: In VB.net it works without the ToString as well. Should be the same in C# i believe, if not, yes a ToString will fix it.

Comment: c# is not VB.NET. Different rules apply, and implicit conversion is one of them

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get a red squiggly under the ".text" that says 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: weird, I tried it again this morning and that worked! I must have had a typo. I will use this code for my project since this was how I wanted it to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass the UI controls to the back-end (where your logic is). Instead, ask the back-end for the result so the front-end can decide what to do with it:

```
internal static class Calculator
{
    public static int Add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;

        if (!int.TryParse(TxtFirstNumber.Text, out firstNumber))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("first number is not a number");
            return;
        }
        else if (!int.TryParse(TxtSecondNumber.Text, out secondNumber))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("second number is not a number");
            return;
        }

        TxtResult.Text = Calculator.Add(firstNumber, secondNumber).ToString();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have also updated the names so that they reflect their meaning and comply with c# standard conventions.

Comment: this code definitely works, thanks. Side question: Is there a way to use TryParse instead of convert when sending the data? Or do I have to use a try catch block to catch the exception thrown if someone enters a non-numerical value in the textbox?

Comment: @Robert Glad to help. Sure, I just edited the answer to show a basic example. In fact, using `Convert` is quite discouraged. Always prefer *Try* methods that don't raise exceptions

Answer (score 1):

`TxtResult` is a TextBox control. You are assigning the sum of two numbers (an integer) to that control. You can't do that. They are not the same type.

You could however convert the integer to a string, and then assign that string to the `Text` property of the TextBox control like this:

```
TxtResult.Text = (FirstNumber + SecondNumber).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep logic separate from presentation

```
class class1
{
    public static int AddTwoNumbers(int FirstNumber, int SecondNumber)
    {
        return FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
}

public partial class form1 : Form
{
    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(TxtFirstNumber.Text);
       int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(TxtSecondNumber.Text);
       int result = Class1.AddTwoNumbers(v1, v2);
       TxtResult.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```